# Blueprint CSS affecting appearance of jQuery datepicker

Tags: css, jquery-ui, blueprint-css

Does anyone have any pointers how to to fix the styling issue presented when using jquery ui's datepicker along side blueprint css framework? Specifically the table with the dates appears larger (wider) than the container it sits in.

Answer (score 6):

I tried the other answers, but they didn't do it for me. After playing around with the problem for a few hours I came up with a solution that works for me (Blueprint 1.0, Jquery UI 1.8.5, tested with Smoothness, Redmond and Dark Hive themes in Chrome and IE):

```
/* remove blue backgrounds - separate for TH to work in IE */
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr:nth-child(even) td,  
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr.even td {
  background-color:inherit;
 }
.ui-datepicker-calendar thead th {
  background-color:inherit;
 }
/* set correct line height */
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody tr td {  
  line-height: 1.1;
}
/* (optional)  make same size as example */
.ui-datepicker { font-size: 0.9em; }
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. It works on multiple themes as well.

Comment: Worked for me only after I applied a theme. Before that, it had extremely large columns. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Added the following CSS to solve the problem:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar table{
  margin: 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar th , .ui-datepicker-calendar td {
  padding: 0; text-align: center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help.

I found I had to make a couple more alterations before it looked closer to the default styling:

```
/*JQUERY-UI + BLUEPRINT CSS CALENDAR FIX*/
.ui-datepicker-calendar table{
  margin: 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar th , .ui-datepicker-calendar td {
  padding: 0; text-align: center; background:white; color:#333;  }
.ui-datepicker-calendar th{
  padding: 5px 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar td{
  padding:0 2px 2px 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar td a{
  padding:0 1px 0 0; }
.ui-datepicker {
  font-size:0.8em; }
```

Answer (score 0):

oneBelizean was on the right track, but it wouldn't work for me until I qualified the th and td selectors with table:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar table{
  margin: 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar table th , .ui-datepicker-calendar table td {
  padding: 0; text-align: center; }
```

After doing this, I didn't need any of the extra stuff Simon added.

Answer (score 0):

I found I had to access the elements very specifically and remove some padding.

```
/* JQUERY-UI + BLUEPRINT CSS CALENDAR FIX */
.ui-datepicker table{
  margin: 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr th , .ui-datepicker tbody tr td {
  background:white; color:#333;  }
.ui-datepicker-calendar thead tr th{
  padding: 5px 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td{
  padding:0 2px 2px 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td a{
  padding:0 1px 0 0; }
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  font-size:0.8em; }
```